# How do I turn my create-react-app project into a single html file with embeded js?

Tags: html, reactjs, create-react-app

I made a simple create-react-app project as a test assignment for a new job. I'm already finished with the project, but there's a catch:

I must turn the project in as **a single html file** with embeded js and css.

How do I turn my create-react-app project into a single file?

---

**Edit:** Running npm build doesn't solve my issue, as it builds the project, but the result **is not a single html file!** - it generates an index.html **plus a static/ folder** to import sources from.

I could hand-paste those I guess, but am looking for a more elegant solution!

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build

Comment: Running npm build builds the project, but the result **is not a single html file!** - it generates an index.html **plus a static/ folder** to import sources from.

Comment: You can't. That's not how React projects are meant to be put together.

Comment: Maybe the employer put you on a test, to see what you submit, send in the build folder and ask them to run by `serve`. Or do not use CRA and go with [CDN](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html), and load React statically into the index with script tag .... the old school style

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi they do indeed want to test me, I explicitly asked them about the single file part of the assignment and they confirmed that it's what they want from me :)

Comment: So, it seems you have no more options to go CDN way,which needs lots of rewrites, you can find very good tutorials on Youtube. I recommend [this one](https://youtu.be/dUlz4tc9LSo)

Comment: @MichalKurz It could be very cool feature especially for offline projects. I need the same and I don't understand who downvoted this question.

Answer (score -3):

Run this command:

```
npm run build
```

Comment: Running npm build builds the project, but the result **is not a single html file!** - it generates an index.html **plus a static/ folder** to import sources from.

Comment: You can't then. You can then copy paste the js content in script tag from generated one.